# Ferrite cores ANSYS MAXWELL - where to find more BP curves?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, ferrite

i need more than one BP curve (for different freq.) for loss estimation. But in datasheet there is for only one frequency, so dont know how to solve this? Without mailing distributor, that will be last case.
https://semic.cz/!old/files/pdf_www/CF297.pdf
Thanks a lot!
Or if you know where i can download libraries for this (or other way how to solve this), which will contain material CF297/N97 i would appreciate that! thanks
[image]

Comment: What is a BP curve?

Comment: i have added picture of BP curve from TDK datasheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *i need more than one BP curve (for different freq.) for loss
> estimation. But in datasheet there is for only one frequency, so don't
> know how to solve this?*

You can use this graph to estimate the losses at different frequencies: -

[image]

I've marked on the graph where 100 kHz is for regular magnetic permeability (solid line) and the loss associated with it (dotted line). So, if your operating frequency was (say) 300 kHz, I would expect the losses to rise by 50/23 or 2.17 times.